# how to make gmail like URL using Angular2 routers?

Tags: angular, url, router

I am working on routers using Angular2. The url I want to make is like 'https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#search/angular/15y58930e5a82911'. This URL comes up when searching with 'Angular' in mail box and then selecting a particular mail from the searching result. But my application does not achieve it.

My application structure is like this, I have AppModule and SearchModule. 
Each module has its own routers.

app.routes.ts

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './home/index#HomeModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    loadChildren: './search/index#SearchModule'
  }
];
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: `
    <app-header></app-header>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 `
})
export class AppComponent {

}
```

search.routes.ts

```
export const SearchRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchContainerComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'intro', pathMatch: 'full'  },
      { path: 'intro', component: SearchIntroComponent  },
      { path: 'artist/:id', component: DetailViewComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

search.container.component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-container',
  template: `
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <app-search (search)="searchArtist($event);"> </app-search>
      <artist-list
        [artistList]="artistsList"
        (artist)="displaySelectedArtist($event)"
      ></artist-list>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})

export class SearchContainerComponent implements OnInit {


}
```

With these codes, in the left panel, there is supposed to display a list of artist as a result of search. In the right panel, the first artist's detail information is supposed to be shown automatically. And the corresponding URL becomes http://xxx.xxx.com/#/artist/11. 11 is the first artist gotten after searching the artist with 'coffee'. However, the URL I want is http://xxx.xxx.com/#/search/coffee/artist/11' instead of http://xxx.xxx.com/#/artist/11.

Could anyone of you give some advice about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your route configuration:

```
export const SearchRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'search',
    component: SearchContainerComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'intro', pathMatch: 'full'  },
      { path: 'intro', component: SearchIntroComponent  },
      { path: 'artist/:id', component: DetailViewComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

Defines what your routes will look like. If you don't want "search" in the url, then you can remove its path like this:

```
export const SearchRoutes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SearchContainerComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'intro', pathMatch: 'full'  },
      { path: 'intro', component: SearchIntroComponent  },
      { path: 'artist/:id', component: DetailViewComponent }
    ]
  },
];
```

OR move your artist route so it is no longer a child of the search route.

Comment: Yes, I know the principle and did the way you showed but it was not working as I expected. Therefore, I get to add 'search' even it is defined already in root router. Anyway, I am looking into it more and trying to figure it out. I have been watching your lectures in Pluralsight :)

Answer (score 0):

I have Implemented similar to this in my project. Hope you like it. i got this idea from https://angular.io/api in this page when you search it will update the address bar automatically.

go ahead and try this

Component file

```
import { NavigationExtras, ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router' 
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-employees',
   template: `
   <form [formGroup]="search">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Search" formControlName="Empname" />
       <input type="text" placeholder="Search" formControlName="destination" />
   </form>
   ` 
})

export class EmployeesComponent implements OnInit {
    search: FormGroup;

  constructor(
     private route: ActivatedRoute,
     private router: Router,
     private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
     createForm();

     this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(params => {

        this.search.setValue({
            Empname: params.get('name') || '',
            destination: params.get('destination') || ''
        });

    });

    this.search.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        this.onSearchValueChange();
    });

  }


  onSearchValueChange() {

      let obj = new Object();
      const name = this.search.get('Empname').value;
      const des = this.search.get('destination').value;

      !!name && (obj['name'] = name); 
      !!des && (obj['destination'] = des);

      const navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
          relativeTo: this.route,
          queryParams: obj,
          replaceUrl: true
      };

      this.router.navigate(['../employees'], navigationExtras);
  }


  createForm() {
     this.search = this.fb.group({
        Empname: '',
        destination: ''
     });
  }
}
```

Only thing you have to do in this component is that update the name of the input according to your input model names. I'm using form builder here.

go this link for details about NavigationExtras
https://angular.io/api/router/NavigationExtras